# How do I change app icon in google play store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I try to publish my first android app on google play store.
App build 8 closed test is reviewed at the moment and build 4 was available for testing.

I have an issue with app icon show in play store - it looks to me it is a default one, instead of one uploaded in google play console (the one 512x512px).

You can see it by clicking on this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.dietplannerpro.listonix

It looks like this:
[image: default app icon]

and should look like this:
[image: listonix icon]

Could anyone advise please on how to update the icon in google play store?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have filled `Main store listing` in `Grow` section and you have also complete `App content` in `Policy and programs` section, the icon will be visible when review will be validated. You can submit for review in `Closed testing` if you don't want to put on production.

Comment: I see... OK. Thanks. I will wait until review is validated.